# PyCairo surface.write_to_png too slow

Tags: python-3.x, performance, pycairo

I have to make a project that creates various images with pycairo and then uses all those images in ffmpeg to make a video. But the problem is that the method cairo.surface.write_to_png is too slow, so the code takes almost 1 minute to run. And i'm not finding anything that could make the program faster. Can someone help me ?

This is the method that is slowing the code:

```
    def rectangle(self, xstart, ystart, xfinish, yfinish, linewidth=5, outcolor=(0, 0, 0, 1), 
                  fillcolor=(0, 0, 0, 0), steps=1000, animation=0):
        ctx = self.context
        w = (xfinish-xstart) if xfinish >= xstart else (xstart-xfinish)
        h = (yfinish-ystart) if yfinish >= ystart else (ystart-yfinish)
        if fillcolor != (0, 0, 0, 0):
            ctx.set_source_rgba(fillcolor[0], fillcolor[1], fillcolor[2], fillcolor[3])
            ctx.fill_preserve()
        ctx.set_source_rgba(outcolor[0], outcolor[1], outcolor[2], outcolor[3])
        ctx.set_line_width(linewidth)
        if self.animate:
            c = 0
            i = 0
            clist, ilist = [], []
            cstep = w/steps
            istep = h/steps
            count = 0
            try:
                lastf = os.listdir('C:/Users/ferna/PycharmProjects/Draw/test')[-1][5:8]
            except IndexError:
                lastf = 0
                pass
            while True:
                if count != 0:
                    ctx.save()
                    ctx.set_source_rgba(self.background[0], self.background[1], 
                                        self.background[2], self.background[3])
                    ctx.set_line_width(linewidth+2)
                    ctx.rectangle(xstart, ystart, c-cstep, i-istep)
                    ctx.fill_preserve()
                    ctx.stroke()
                    ctx.restore()
                ctx.rectangle(xstart, ystart, c, i)
                ctx.stroke()
                self.surface.write_to_png(os.fsdecode(f'C:/Users/ferna/PycharmProjects/Draw/oi/teste{count + int(lastf):0>3.0f}.png'))
                clist.append(c)
                ilist.append(i)
                c += cstep
                i += istep
                count += 1
                if c > w and i > h:
                    break
        ctx.rectangle(xstart, ystart, w, h)
        ctx.stroke()
```

Comment: You should retry your question on CodeReview, the platform aims to make working code better. [so] is mostly for code that dosent work. Anyway, I would rewrite your code that you have two threads or processes, one for creating your image and one that shows your data. Instead of write to png you can transfer the data as bytes and use a stream. Hope it works out for you, happy coding.